# how to disable certain cloud code to automatically include in auto schema graphql parse-server?

Tags: parse-platform, graphql, parse-cloud-code

While activate graphql function in parse-server, i got this warning msg in my log:

```
warn: Function my-cloud-code-function could not be added to the auto schema because GraphQL names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.
```

I know i can remove the warning by fixing the function name and update it to the proper name format. But what i really want is to disable certain function to be automatically included in auto schema graphql parse-server. How can i do that? I believe there should be some parse server graphql option to exclude it from the list, but i can not found.

Comment: what is the version of Parse Server that you are using?

Comment: i am using v 4.3.0. that the latest version for now

Comment: I've just checked the code and there is currently no way to get rid of those warnings. You can open an issue at the open source repo. I believe it would be a good addition.